# Downloading excel(.xlsx) with blob and FileSaver.js in vue project getting coruppted

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, savefiledialog, filesaver.js

I am trying to download file by sending an Api request in my Vue project, and with response data I am trying to save the file using blob and FileSaver.js

```
sendAjaxCall.then(response => {
      let file = new Blob([response.data], {type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'})
      FileSaver.saveAs(file, 'Export2.xlsx')
}
```

But I can not open the file, it is getting corrupted.

Comment: are you still having issue with this ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

try this

```
     return Vue.axios.get(`api/excel_sheet`, {
        responseType: 'blob',
      }).then(response => {
      FileSaver.saveAs(response.data, 'Export2.xlsx')
};
```

u need to specify the response type as blob

Comment: Thank you Mazino,
Actully I was missing the responseType, your solution working. and also 
I have soloved it by sending the responseType = 'arraybuffer' and blob the response and then saved it.

Comment: Thank you @MazinoSUkah.. It worked like a charm.. :)